# RabbitMQ and django celery

Tags: rabbitmq, django-celery, pika, python-pika

i am using pika client for creating connection to rabbitmq for some pub-sub project. A direct call to the client work fine but when i am trying to create a channel inside a celery task i getting an error.

### raised unexpected: OSError(9, 'Bad file descriptor')

#### This is the code for creating connection

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host=get_secret("RABBIT_MQ_HOST"),
    credentials=pika_credentials.PlainCredentials(
        get_secret("RABBIT_MQ_USERNAME"),
        get_secret("RABBIT_MQ_PASSWORD")
    )
))
channel = connection.channel()
```

I am getting error at connection.channel().

How can i create connection in celery (broker is also rabbitmq).